# How would I manipulate one set of list group items without affecting the others?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a AJAX request that puts information into the list group towards the bottom of the code provided.
However, this method changes all of the list group items within the DOM.
How would I force the AJAX requests to populate the second list group without bothering the first.
I've tried using ID's in lieu of class names for the jQuery selector but it still has not worked.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //calls repos for list group items
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "https://api.github.com/users/WolfgangHall/repos?sort=updated",
        success: function(repos) {
            for (var i = 0; i < repos.length; i++) {
                var newListItem = buildListGroup (repos[i]);
                $(".list-group").append(newListItem);
            }
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
            alert("Something is wrong here");
        }
    });
    function buildListGroup (repoData) {
        var commitsApiUrl = "https://api.github.com/repos/";
        commitsApiUrl += repoData.owner.login + "/";
        commitsApiUrl += repoData.name + "/commits";

        var newLink = $("<a>")
        .attr("href", commitsApiUrl)
        .addClass("list-group-item")
        .append(repoData.full_name);

        return newLink
    }
});


<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">Front end</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <ul class="list-group">
                    <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="panel panel-success">
            <div class="panel-heading">Back end</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <ul class="list-group">
                        <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div> 
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="githubTab">
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="list-group"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <th>sha</th>
                <th>Author</th>
                <th>Message</th>
                <th>Date</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody></tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Will it always be the *second*, or will it always be the *last*, list-group to which you want to append the new data/elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can target the second item with class of 'list-group' with the jQuery 'eq' method like this:

replace:

```
$(".list-group").append(newListItem);
```

with

```
 $(".list-group").eq(1).append(newListItem);
```

Here it is working: http://codepen.io/caleboleary/pen/qbBMgG

Comment: `.eq()` is 0-indexed so it should be `.eq(1)`

Answer (score 0):

[`:nth-child()`](https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) (1-indexed) or [`:eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) (0-indexed) selectors should work.

```
$(".list-group:nth-child(2)").append(newListItem);
```

or

```
$(".list-group:eq(1)").append(newListItem);
```